# File not found java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) GLIDE?

Tags: java, android, camera, imageview, android-glide

I saved an image in the folder inside android/data/com.myappliction/files/Pictures/file.jpg. whenever i try to open using glide. i get the following log.

Code:

```
public class profile extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView;
    File file = new File("Android/data/com.example.cogniace/files/Pictures/profile.jpg");
    private static final String TAG = profile.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
       imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        Glide.with(this)
                  .load(file)

                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_sync_black_24dp)
                //.error(R.drawable.camera_icon)
                .into(imageView);
```

Exception:

```
2019-10-22 16:40:05.337 30115-30115/com.example.cogniace W/Glide: Load failed for Android/data/com.example.cogniace/files/Pictures/profile.jpg with size [1002x1506]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There were 3 causes:
    java.io.IOException(File unsuitable for memory mapping)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(Android/data/com.example.cogniace/files/Pictures/profile.jpg (No such file or directory))
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory))
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.nio.ByteBuffer, LOCAL
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.IOException(File unsuitable for memory mapping)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.IOException: File unsuitable for memory mapping
      Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, LOCAL
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(Android/data/com.example.cogniace/files/Pictures/profile.jpg (No such file or directory))
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: Android/data/com.example.cogniace/files/Pictures/profile.jpg (No such file or directory)
      Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor, LOCAL
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory))
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2019-10-22 16:40:05.338 30115-30115/com.example.cogniace I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 3)
    java.io.IOException: File unsuitable for memory mapping
        at com.bumptech.glide.util.ByteBufferUtil.fromFile(ByteBufferUtil.java:38)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.ByteBufferFileLoader$ByteBufferFetcher.loadData(ByteBufferFileLoader.java:61)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:279)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:431)
2019-10-22 16:40:05.339 30115-30115/com.example.cogniace I/Glide: Root cause (2 of 3)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: Android/data/com.example.cogniace/files/Pictures/profile.jpg (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:231)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:165)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.FileLoader$StreamFactory$1.open(FileLoader.java:142)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.FileLoader$StreamFactory$1.open(FileLoader.java:139)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.FileLoader$FileFetcher.loadData(FileLoader.java:71)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherFailed(DecodeJob.java:408)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.onLoadFailed(SourceGenerator.java:130)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.ByteBufferFileLoader$ByteBufferFetcher.loadData(ByteBufferFileLoader.java:66)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:279)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:431)
2019-10-22 16:40:05.341 30115-30115/com.example.cogniace I/Glide: Root cause (3 of 3)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.openInternal(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:313)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.open(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:211)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.FileLoader$FileDescriptorFactory$1.open(FileLoader.java:166)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.FileLoader$FileDescriptorFactory$1.open(FileLoader.java:163)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.FileLoader$FileFetcher.loadData(FileLoader.java:71)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherFailed(DecodeJob.java:408)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.onLoadFailed(SourceGenerator.java:130)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.FileLoader$FileFetcher.loadData(FileLoader.java:76)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherFailed(DecodeJob.java:408)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.onLoadFailed(SourceGenerator.java:130)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.ByteBufferFileLoader$ByteBufferFetcher.loadData(ByteBufferFileLoader.java:66)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:279)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:431)
2019-10-22 16:40:10.390 30115-30177/com.example.cogniace V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Comment: i paste as it is

Comment: Why don't you keep in drawables folder instead of pasting it data folders.

Comment: I captured and save image using camera, and saved the file in internal storage.. if is there any way to save it in drawable folder, please say how to save it in the drawable foldr.

Comment: You didn't mentioned that in your question.

Comment: `new File("Android/data/com.example.cogniace/files/Pictures/profile.jpg");` That is not a valid path you use there. No wonder you get a FileNotFoundException.

Comment: Please show how you saved an image in internal memory. If you could you used a real path.

Comment: ` private  File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name

        String imageFileName = "profile";
     File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    File image = new File(
                /* prefix */
                         /* suffix */
             storageDir,
                imageFileName+
                ".png"/* directory */
        );   // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }`,

Comment: use System.getProperty("user.dir") to get the current directory path. Then append the relative path to the file that you want to access.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass URI of the image. Try with this: -

```
 Glide.with(this)
      .load(imageUri)
```

OR

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(new File(fileUri.getPath()))
```

Comment: how to use imgUri?? I am new to android programming